# Rails Model Calculation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have an `Opportunity` model and its attributes include:

```
derated_sales
est_full_value
est_workshare
p_win
```

I am trying to calculate the following:

```
derated_sales = est_full_value.to_f * (est_workshare.to_i/100).to_f * (p_win.to_i/100).to_f
```

Here is the code for my model:

```
 class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
     after_save :calculate_derated_value
     def calculate_derated_value          
       opportunity.derated_sales = est_full_value.to_f * (est_workshare.to_i/100).to_f * (p_win.to_i/100).to_f    
     end
 end
```

However, after I click "create", the "derated_sales" I get the error "undefined local variable or method `opportunity'"

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be saying `self.derated_sales`. Since `calculate_derated_value` is call on the instance of Opportunity, anything you call will be called on the object.

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :calculate_derated_value
    def calculate_derated_value       
       self.derated_sales = self.est_full_value.to_f * (self.est_workshare.to_i/100).to_f * (self.p_win.to_i/100).to_f    
    end
end
```

Also, if you want to save the value to the database, you should be setting it in `before_save` instead of `after_save`. `after_save` happens after the record gets created in the database.

Comment: I tried that, but the value still won't show up. Even if I put self.derated_sales = 100..

Comment: yeah after i click "create", it is suppose to show up when i print out on the index page @vimsha

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You should be setting derated_sales in before_save. If you set it in after_save, it will not be saved in the database and when the object is reloaded in index, it will loose the value